# Obtaining a list of JSONs with re.split

Tags: python, string, parsing, split, python-re

I'm trying to parse a string containing multiple json objects using the re.split method. However I can't find a pattern that works as I want.

**Received string**

```
'{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}'
```

**My code to parse it**

```
def parseMultipleJson(multijson):
    print(re.split('[}+{]', multijson))
```

**Expected result**

```
['{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}','{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}', '{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}']
```

**Actual result**

```
['', '"project":"rapidjson","stars":10', '', '"project":"rapidjson","stars":10', '', '"project":"rapidjson","stars":10', '']
```

I know I'm messing up with the pattern but I've been trying other variations for a while by now and I can't find a way to achieve the expected result

Comment: Where are you getting that string? It would probably be far easier to modify the producer to give you something reasonable to work with.

Comment: @chepner not really that doable: the string comes from a pipe, so if the receiving process crashes and is rebooted, the pipe will be filled with this stuff. I can't even tell the receiver to only read a fixed amount of bytes because the size of a json will never be fixed. Nor can I really make the receiving process waste too many milliseconds just to retrieve older data, it has to be as fast as possible

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that you read only complete JSON objects from the pipe? At some point, it seems you can  already identify the transition from `}` that ends one object and `{` that starts another. Since ASCII control characters cannot appear directly in JSON, you can use any of them to delimit the objects in the stream.

Comment: @chepner mm, guess I'll try to parse the string some other way then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried so many options to capture the pattern and end up with this:

```
def parseMultipleJson(multijson):
    print(re.findall(r'{.{33}', multijson))
```

This gives you expected output. But it uses re.findall method rather than re.split.

Answer (score 2):

Expression `'(?<=})'` working for it, which means that you are looking for every pattern that ends with `}`. See [positive lookbehind assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

**Actual result**

```
['{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}', '{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}', '{"project":"rapidjson","stars":10}', '']
```